# Receiving Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout

Tags: javascript, jestjs, supertest

So, I've got the following test using Jest and Supertest:

```
describe('GET /healthcheck', () => {
test('Should return 200 in the GET / health check', (done) => {
    request
      .get('/healthcheck')
      .set({ correlationId: mock.correlationId, Accept: 'application/json' })
      .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return err;
        expect(res.body).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({status: 'UP'}));
        return done();
      });
  });
```

And I'm getting the async timeout error. I'm also getting an EADDRIUSE, so it may be the cause of the timeouts, I don't know.

I've already tried to add some flags like runInBand and maxWorkers on jest, but none worked. I've tried adding async/await to the test call, and it didn't work as well. I added jest.setTimeout and it didn't work too. I may be getting out of options.

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Try calling `done(error)` in the error case.

Comment: Like return done(err) or just done(err)?

Comment: `return done(err)`

Comment: Did it, same behaviour

Comment: You added jest.setTimeout() with a value greater than 5000 and still have the 5000ms error message?

Comment: Yeah, I've tested it, I also added jestTimeout on the test script on the package.json and the timeouts errors still occurred. As I've said before, it may be due to the EADRRINUSE error that I'm also getting.

Comment: ok but does the error message says 5000ms even when you do setTimeout(6000) or setTimeout(10000) or does it take into account the value you use in setTimeout()?

Comment: No, the message changes to the time out I set.

Comment: Ok so there is only one problem, port is already in use. Can you edit your question to add more details about how you are building "request" and if your server/app being tested is doing "listen()" inside its own module? If you did like `const request = supertest(app)` where app is doing "listen()", you will need to remove that "listen()" from the app's module and put it outside.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/568)

Comment: The server configuration is made in an external file called server.ts that's being used to start the supertest server

Comment: I've changed some parts of my code after looking at the Github link you sent. But the timeout errors are still occurring